# SELECT common value from two similar columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table, `matches`, which contains sports fixture data with fields including `home_pom` (home player of the match) and `away_pom`. I need to call a query to find the top 5 values across those two fields (i.e. the 5 people with the most player of the match awards overall from season x), with the capacity to output the number of occurrences and the name of the player.

I have no real clue where to start with the SELECT function.

The matches table contains a `league_id` field which corresponds to a separate `leagues` table, called to $league_id earlier in the page. There's currently no separate `players` table - I thought it would probably be redundant since this is pretty much the only thing I can consider it being relevant for.

i.e.

```
match_id | homepom | awaypom | league_id  
1        | Joe A   | Jane B  |  2  
2        | Joe F   | Jane G  |  2  
3        | Jane B  | Joe F   |  2
```

to list Joe F and Jane B as having 2 pom awards, and Jane G and Joe A as having one.

```php
$host="cust-mysql-123-05"; // Host name 
$username="unsn_637140_0003"; // Mysql username 
$password="mypw"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="nsnetballcouk_637140_db3"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$areatoleaguepom=$_GET['area'];
$seasontoleaguepom=$_GET['season'];
$divisiontoleaguepom=$_GET['division'];
$leaguepom_query=("SELECT league_id FROM leagues WHERE area_id='$areatoleaguepom' AND      season_id='$seasontoleaguepom' AND division_id='$divisiontoleaguepom'");
$leaguepom_result=mysql_query($leaguepom_query);
$leaguepom_row=mysql_fetch_array($leaguepom_result);
$leaguepom_id=$leaguepom_row['league_id'];

$toppom_query=(
"SELECT
player,
COUNT(player) as count
FROM (SELECT homepom AS player
FROM matches
WHERE league_id='$leaguepom_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT awaypom AS player
FROM matches
WHERE league_id='$leaguepom_id'
) as players
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
");

$toppom_result=mysql_query($toppom_query);
while ($toppom_row=mysql_fetch_array($toppom_result));

echo $toppom_row['player'] . " " . $toppom_row['count'] . "<br>";
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You should be able to do something with `count()` and `group by`, but it's difficult to give you a good answer without a little more info. Do you have a player table that the `home_pom` and `away_pom` fields reference? How do you know what season a match is?

Comment: You will receive the better answers if you post your data structure (without unnecessary fields), some example data and example of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: edited this up with a little more detail - apologies for the haziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit overcomplicated, but anyway...

```
SELECT
    player,
    COUNT(player) as count
FROM (
    SELECT homepom AS player
    FROM matches
    WHERE homepom IS NOT NULL AND homepom != '' AND league_id = xxx AND other_things
    UNION ALL
    SELECT awaypom AS player
    FROM matches
    WHERE awaypom IS NOT NULL AND awaypom != '' AND league_id = xxx AND other_things
) as players
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

You merge the home_pom and away_pom in one column, then do a group by to count who has the most.

Edit: removed the player table...

Comment: That looks exactly like how in my head I thought it might if I knew what I was doing at all. Thanks so much.

Comment: How do I output this to echo? I'm using `$toppom_row['player']` and `$toppom_row['count']` - this wrong? Through `$toppom_row=(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($toppom_query)))`

Comment: Sounds right, but I can't tell if it should work without seeing the rest of the code. Also make sure you are getting results by running the query directly 1-st (from your mysql client).

Comment: My phpmyadmin says the query's successful but not seeing any results in live play. Huh.

Comment: Try running only one of the inner queries (`SELECT homepom FROM matches WHERE league_id = xxx AND other_things`).

Comment: still nothing. updated the OP with an extended code segment from the php file which is included in the main page as a sidebar.

Comment: I tested the query with a dummy table and it seems to work. Are you sure you have the correct `$leaguepom_id` and actual matches in there?

Comment: Hmmm. The $leaguepom_id thing is identical to another variable that works perfectly fine. The matches in the database definitely have homepom defined. Hmm.

Comment: Try to get it running in phpmyadmin first (if it doesn't work there there's no way its gonna work in your script). If it doesn't work try simplifying it - run only the inner `SELECT`'s or only one of them.   When you get it working try it in PHP but with hardcoded value for the `leaguepom_id`.

Comment: Works in phpmyadmin, returns the array perfectly. At first I thought it was simply my not having defaulted the homepom and awaypom fields to NULL, but after having changed nothing is showing still.

Comment: Yeah good point about the extra WHERE clauses. It's still not outputting anything though! So strange.

Comment: You have a `;` after your `while` loop. It doesn't do anything. Remove it and maybe add some `{}` to it.

Comment: Is there a way I can like rep you to absolute high heaven for pointing that out, because that was what was killing the echo. Thanks SO much. I might be able to go to sleep now!

Comment: It is an annoying mistake. I usually avoid ifs and loops without `{}`'s because of errors similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

[`GREATEST(home_pom, away_pom)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) will return max of `home_pom` and `away_pom`. So, something like that:

```
select * from your_table
where season = x
order by greatest(home_pom, away_pom)
desc limit 5
```

- `where` clause take all player records for season `x`;
- `order by .. desc` sort all player records by what you want;
- `limit 5` will take top 5 players.

Comment: Is there a way to spin this to also access the number relating to each player? Perhaps with mysql_num_rows?

Comment: Add `group by player_id` clause just before `order by`